# Proper way to restore database transaction level from read uncommitted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get data from a table which is excessively updated. Dirty read is not a problem for me. I decided to use read uncommitted in my stored procedure.

Then I added this line before select:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

I learned that this code scope is connection, unlike nolock. I heard you should change it to default after your work is done is that right?

Do I have to just add

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

end of the line? I could not find any example on the web where isolation level is changed back after work is done. Is there any example?

Comment: The transaction level set inside the SPROC will not be inherited by the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only one of the isolation level options can be set at a time, **and it remains set for that connection until it is explicitly changed**. All read operations performed within the transaction operate under the rules for the specified isolation level unless a table hint in the FROM clause of a statement specifies different locking or versioning behavior for a table.
>
> ...
>
> **If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked.** For example, if you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure returns control to the batch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx